# How to get Java split to work on Cyrillic string

Tags: java, split

I have the following situation:

1. Reading from the database a field, that contains Cyrillic letters.

   ```
   String title = (String)dbTable.getAttribute("title");
   ```
2. Show this title in JSP page - if the title contains more than 10 words, show only first 10 words, otherwise show full title.

Full title shows well.

For getting 10 words from the title I used code:

```
      String t1 = (String)dbTable.getAttribute("title");
      String t2 = t1.split("\\w", 11);
      title = t2[10];
```

But got strange results - obviously I'm missing something about method split.

for example

```
t1 = "Внасяне от осигурителя на осигурителните вноски за държавното обществено осигуряване и допълнително задължително пенсионно осигуряване върху начислени, но неизплатени възнаграждения или върху неначислени възнаграждения, отнасящи се за труд, положен през месец Март 2012 г. (първият работен ден след 30 Април 2012 г. е 02 Май 2012 г.)";
t2 returns "г. е 02 Май 2012 г.) "
```

which is not the result I want.

I tried to see what is in t2[0] , t2[1] so on - but also didn't get expected results - in t2[0] I got first 5 words from the beginning of that string - not just first one word.

Question is what I did wrong with split, or how to get split working on Cyrillic string, or please suggest some workaround.

Comment: What do you expect the result to be?
Are you sure you understand the second parameter of split correctly?

Comment: The expected result would be: `"Внасяне от осигурителя на осигурителните вноски за държавното обществено осигуряване"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use a regex here. For extremely simple parsing, doing it manually is faster than doing it with a regex (and, in this case, far simpler).

```
public class FirstTenTest {
  public static void main (String... args) {
    String myString = "Внасяне от осигурителя на осигурителните вноски за държавното обществено осигуряване и допълнително задължително пенсионно осигуряване върху начислени, но неизплатени възнаграждения или върху неначислени възнаграждения, отнасящи се за труд, положен през месец Март 2012 г. (първият работен ден след 30 Април 2012 г. е 02 Май 2012 г.)";

    System.out.println(firstTenWords(myString));
  }

  public static String firstTenWords(String input) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int spaceCount = 0;
    for(char c : input.toCharArray()) {
      if (c == ' ') spaceCount++;
      if (spaceCount == 10) break;
      sb.append(c);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  } 
}
```

### Output:

```
Внасяне от осигурителя на осигурителните вноски за държавното обществено осигуряване
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! Very nice workaround for Cyrillic letters.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `"\\s+"` instead of `"\\w"`

Comment: Tried, but still got not expected result.

Answer (score 1):

`String[] t2 = t1.split("\\w", 11);` actually means: split the string t1 [by a word character (a-z, A-Z, 0-9 or _)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), and give me only 11 splitted members max.

[The character class for whitespace is](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) `\\s`

Answer (score 0):

Steps that you can implement from my understanding not sure about cyrilic lettters

1.Get the length of the title

2.Check the length of the string

3.If the length is greater than 10 then use title.substring(startindex, endIndex) return it

4.If title < 10 then return the title actual string

Comment: 3 step will return 10 letters, I want 10 words.